# The missing folds

Tags: haskell, recursion, fold, language-features, haskell-prelude

If you want to fold a list, I see four ways to do it.

#### Fold from the right of the list, with the recursive term on the right

> foldrr (-) 100 [1..10] = 1 - (2 - (3 - (4 - (5 - (6 - (7 - (8 - (9 - (10 - (100))))))))))  = 95

```
foldrr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldrr step zero (x:xs) = step x (foldrr step zero xs)
foldrr _    zero []     = zero
```

#### Fold from the right of the list, with the recursive term on the left

> foldrl (-) 100 [1..10] = ((((((((((100) - 10) - 9) - 8) - 7) - 6) - 5) - 4) - 3) - 2) - 1 = 45

```
foldrl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldrl step zero (x:xs) = step (foldrl step zero xs) x
foldrl _    zero []     = zero
```

#### Fold from the left of the list with the recursive term on the right

> foldlr (-) 100 [1..10] = 10 - (9 - (8 - (7 - (6 - (5 - (4 - (3 - (2 - (1 - (100)))))))))) = 105

```
foldlr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldlr step zero (x:xs) = foldlr step (step x zero) xs
foldlr _    zero []     = zero
```

#### Fold from the left of the list with the recursive term on the left

> foldll (-) 100 [1..10] = ((((((((((100) - 1) - 2) - 3) - 4) - 5) - 6) - 7) - 8) - 9) - 10 = 45

```
foldll :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldll step zero (x:xs) = foldll step (step zero x) xs
foldll _    zero []     = zero
```

---

Only two of these folds made it into Prelude as `foldr` and `foldl`. Was there any reason to just include two folds, and why those two?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`foldrl` and `foldlr` don't add any expressive power: they are just the same as the other two folds but with the folding function flipped.

```
foldrl f = foldr (flip f)
foldlr f = foldl (flip f)

-- Or this, if you prefer
foldrl = foldr . flip
foldlr = foldl . flip
```

But it is not so easy to define `foldl` in terms of `foldr`, so providing them both is useful.

Comment: Why do `foldr (flip f)` and `foldl` always  yield the same result for the non-commutative `-` operation, but `foldl (flip f)`/`foldr` do not?

Comment: @ftor Because `-` follows the identity `(a-b)-c = (a-c)-b`. In general, all four results may be different, but not with `-`.

Comment: @ftor, there is a general identity of that nature: `foldl f b xs = foldr (flip f) b (reverse xs)`. For finite lists, it's also true that `foldr c n xs = foldl (flip c) n (reverse xs)`.

Comment: Another one that always holds: `foldr c n (reverse xs) = foldl (flip c) n xs`.